# Is there a way to open a proxy from the agent nodes to the master in Azure AKS?

Tags: azure-container-service

With `kubectl proxy` I can open a proxy from my machine to the master node in the kubernetes cluster of my current context.

Is there any way I can do the same from the nodes of a managed cluster in Azure AKS?

---

For context, the thing I want to do is to use [Linkerd backed by k8s service discovery](https://linkerd.io/config/head/linkerd/index.html#k8s-configuration), but that doesn't support TLS at the moment and the recommendation in their docs is to run `kubectl proxy` on each node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a `kubectl proxy` container in the pod alongside Linkerd. For example:

`- name: kubectl
  image: buoyantio/kubectl:v1.8.5
  args:
  - "proxy"
  - "-p"
  - "8001"`

Complete example:
https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd-examples/blob/99e33284860a35228dccc23a8810374b02f24c26/k8s-daemonset/k8s/linkerd.yml#L103